# Is it possible to call a powerapps javascript web resource from PowerAutomate?

Tags: javascript, model, power-automate, powerapps, webresource

i have a model-driven powerapp application that uses a web resource (javascript) to   updates a  Dataverse tabel. The tabel contains a list of employees. I want to update the Dataverse tabel once a day and identify new employees. Therefor I would like to use a powerautomate trigger that runs each day to call my script inside the PowerApp  webresource. Is that possible? If yes, what powerautomate modules do I use and how to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. You will have to either put your logic into Flow or place your logic to Action/Custom API and call it from Power Automate Flow.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to run my JavaScript directly in powerautomate or would i need to rewrite the code? My code reads and writes values from/to dataverse tabels by using the webapi. I could of course read and write values using the build in powerautomate modulets but would still need to do some dataprocessing in the code.

Comment: You can't use JavaScript in Power Automate. You will have to refactor what you have.